# Delete cookies chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to delete all cookie on certain domain automatically so I have crafted an extension.I am able to view the cookies for the domain but I didn't find any method to delete them

Here is my code the function eraseCookie is just called one time

Any suggestions ?

```
function eraseCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}

$(document).ready(function() {


var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
{
  window.alert(cookies[i]);
  eraseCookie(cookies[i].split("=")[0]);
}

});
```

I am also using jquery but I don't see a problem in that!

```
    {
        "name": "Gapa",
        "version": "0.1",
        "description": "",
        "browser_action":   {
            "default_icon": "sigla.png",
            "default_title": "",
            "popup": "hello.html"
        },
        "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["*://*.google.ro/*"],
          "js": ["jquery-1.8.2.min.js","cookie_handler.js"]
        }
      ],
       "icons": {
          "128":"sigla.png" },
       "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "tabs",
        "*://*.google.ro/*"
      ],
      "manifest_version": 2


    }
```

LE : 
Here is how my script file looks now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
{
  chrome.cookies.remove({"url": ".google.ro", "name":cookies[i].split("=")[0]}, function(deleted_cookie) { window.alert('deleted cookie') });
}

});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First of all you must provide cookies permission in your manifest.

Second of all Chrome provides you with cookies api where remove function is localted:

```
chrome.cookies.remove(object details, function callback);
```

You can use it like that:

```
chrome.cookies.remove({"url": "http://domain.com", "name": "cookieName"}, function(deleted_cookie) { console.log(deleted_cookie); });
```

Try using this to list all cookies for selected domains (inner delete function removes all cookies from this domain):

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "domain.com"}, function(cookies) {
    for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
        chrome.cookies.remove({url: "http://domain.com" + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name});
    }
});
```

In your manifest.json add:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

and in background.js you include proposed function.

Comment: First thanks for your answer I have attached the manifest file to my question and my source. Unfortunatelly is not working!

Comment: Fixed that the function get's called only once and there is no effect on any cookie...what could be wrong ?

Comment: Edited the above code with getAll example. Also forget to add that url must use scheme like http:// or https://

Comment: window.alert("here");
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: "http://google.ro"}, function(cookies) {
    for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
        window.alert("test");
    }
}); Doesn't show the alert test

Comment: From what I know alerts are not available from background page. Do you see any errors in console? Maybe you havent unisntalled and installed extension again after changing manifest?

Comment: You also can't use cookie api inside content script as far as I remember.

Comment: That's what i am doing how can I modify cookie is not from the content script?

Comment: Edited my answer. You must include background.js in manifest and create background.js file. Then include this code in it.

Comment: Is this plugin available anywhere? Been looking for something like this for a while - useful while developing a website.

Comment: @Arkadiusz'flies'Rzadkowolski I would like to delete all the cookies in my browser, So I use `chrome.cookies.getAll({},handleCookies)` to get all the cookies and I move to `chrome.cookies.remove` they prompt me to enter a url to delete a cookie. What is the url that has to be specified for a particular cookie??

Comment: @muthu remove function requires url that is associated with the cookie to be specified.

Comment: @Arkadiusz'flies'Rzadkowolski Is there a way to get the url that has been associated to a cookie?

Comment: getAll returns an array of Cookie objects. They contain all the info you need to build url: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#type-Cookie

Comment: For https vs http you use secure property from cookie object.

Comment: @Arkadiusz'flies'Rzadkowolski From my limited testing I found that I could use *https* for **all** cookies (even those without `secure` flag). The code above was able to remove non-secure cookies with an https url.

Answer (score 13):

I pieced together Arkadiusz's answer and got this working:

In manifest.json:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "https://*/",
    "http://*/"
  ]
```

In background.js:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: ".mydomain.com"}, function(cookies) {
    for(var i=0; i<cookies.length;i++) {
      console.log(cookies[i]);

      chrome.cookies.remove({url: "https://" + cookies[i].domain  + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name});
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with the same permissions and code `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined`.

Comment: @CannonMoyer probably a bit too late, but make sure to declare `cookies` in `permissions`.

Comment: Thanks. The permission syntax to whitelist all domains seems to have changed to   `"permissions": [ "cookies", "<all_urls>"]`