# how can one clear the cookies that are set while using google chrome on linux

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browser, google-chrome-devtools

On linux(Ubuntu 19.04) there is a sqlite database which lives here usually:

```
.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies
```

Removing that clears some of the cookies. However, i would like to also clear the cookies which are set and used in the active session of chrome that is running.

Are the cookies being written to disk at all or do they only get written to disk after chrome is closed?

If the cookies are not being written to disk. Is there a way to hook into devtools of the running session and clear the cookies programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by ”hook info devtools”? Sounds like [RDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) which you can use for the task, indeed.

Comment: Seems like this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029554/3692099

Comment: Thanks. That is an interesting solution for removing cookies for a specific domain. I would like to essentially clear cookies browser wide across all tabs/all domains at a designed interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear cookies from the **Application** panel. See [delete cookies](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies#delete). See also the [clear site data](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/04/devtools#clear) command.

You can programmatically clear cookies from Puppeteer with [page.deleteCookie](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.14.0&show=api-pagedeletecookiecookies).

Comment: So i can use Puppeteer to connect to a running session of chrome over the remote debugging port and clear cookies it seems. This seems like it will work. Thanks.