# Why are cookies not removed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-addons

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029554/865220) answer, but it doesn't seem to work for me. In the request to `https://https.api.pqr.com/folder/` I can see all the cookies still present.

Here is the code:

```
    chrome.cookies.getAll({domain: ".pqr.com"}, async function(cookies) {
      for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        try {
          console.log(cookies[i], "to remove");
          chrome.cookies.remove({url: "http://" + cookies[i].domain  + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name});          
          console.log(cookies[i], "removed");
        } catch (ex) {
          console.log(cookies[i], ex);
        }
        try {
          console.log(cookies[i], "to remove");
          chrome.cookies.remove({url: "https://" + cookies[i].domain  + cookies[i].path, name: cookies[i].name});          
          console.log(cookies[i], "removed");
        } catch (ex) {
          console.log(cookies[i], ex);
        }
      }

      const resp = await fetch("https://https.api.pqr.com/folder/", {
        method: "POST",
        signal: params.signal,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userInput: "someval,
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
          "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
          "Cookie": ''
        },
      });

    });
```